# Why are saturn rings so thin?

Tags: planet, saturn, planetary-ring, saturn-rings

I wonder why saturn rings are so thin ? Rings A, B and C are approximately just 10 meters thick which is extremely thin compared to the size of Saturn. What are the explanations for that ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your answers.

Comment: Stable orbits without latitudinal precession.  Beyond some limit the particles would be all over the place -- kind of like the path of our moon.

Answer (score 3):

Not that [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2nwbst/how_thick_are_saturns_rings/) is the most reliable of sources, but here's a Q&A with a response that is at least consistent with orbital mechanics.

> [Q} Oh. But why doesn't [the original particle set] just scatter
>   around the planet, creating a big "bubble"?
>
> [A]Let's say there's a particle that moves around in an inclined
>   orbit, so it has both a horizontal and vertical component to its
>   velocity. If it collides with something, it'll either get more
>   velocity, or it'll cancel out. If the vertical component is cancelled
>   out, its orbit doesn't change, it just becomes less inclined. If the
>   horizontal component is cancelled out, it'll fall to a different
>   orbit. If you've got lots of particles going in different directions,
>   their vertical components will cancel out, while those not going in
>   the predominant horizontal direction will collide with others, lose
>   their velocity, and fall inward. The net result will be a ring.
>
> [Q]That makes sense in two dimensions. But it doesn't explain why the
>   rings are thin.
>
> [A]If the rings are thick, it means the particles still have a
>   vertical component to the orbit, each being slightly inclined in a
>   different way so as to make up thickness. They would have to move very
>   precisely for them not to collide and cancel out.

Comment: Orbital mechanics is mathematical, not epistemological. Can you explain why you are sure this is "consistent with orbital mechanics"? Otherwise a random uncredited sentence cluster pasted from reddit does not a Stack Exchange answer make.